Change color of polygon in NetLogo using GIS extension
I have a model with a landscape generated from a shapefile using the GIS extension. Here's the (simplified) code used to generate the landscape (LU_2022 is a property of the polygons in the shapefile), including definition of an agent category called "fields":
extensions [gis]

globals [landscape-dataset]

set landscape-dataset gis:load-dataset "FILE.shp"
    
gis:load-coordinate-system "FILE.prj"
gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-of landscape-dataset)

foreach gis:feature-list-of landscape-dataset [
 feature -> let centroid gis:location-of gis:centroid-of feature

 if gis:property-value feature "LU_2022" = "AL" [
  create-fields 1
 ]

 gis:set-drawing-color black
 gis:draw feature 3
        
 if gis:property-value feature "LU_2022" = "AL" [
  gis:set-drawing-color yellow gis:fill feature 2.0 gis:draw feature 0.01
 ]
]

So far, so good, it all works. Now, in a procedure used later on, I want to change the colour of some field polygons.
I have no idea how to do it. Just changing the 'color' attribute of the fields doesn't work:
ask fields [
 set color black
]

There's no error message, just no change to the map of the landscape. Now, I'm guessing that this change needs to be implemented using the GIS extension, but I don't really see how (without redrawing the whole landscape). Any suggestions?

Are you sure that you have fields in your simulation? Once you created an agent in NetLogo you should be able to change the color independent of GIS. I would assume, that you currently don't see this change.

Yeah, the color attribute of the fields changes, but the change is not visible.

I have a solution to a similar problem (river habitat cells based on GIS polygons) in the "reusable building blocks" archive here: https://www.rbb4abm.com/ -- look for "Digital river".
It defines a "cell", a turtle similar to your "field", which has an agentset of the patches in its polygon. You must change the color of the patches, not the cell/field.

Thanks! I'll have to see how to adapt it to my case. Though I'm wondering whether I really need this, given that it doesn't seem particularly straightforward...
